npm command does nothing
I have installed a lower version of node 6.5.0 and npm, showing node -v version but npm -v does nothing. I have checked the path and also installed higher version of node in windows 11 working fine. But the same version working in another machine of windows 11. Not showing error or showing error log in windows event viewer or some where else. Is there anything need to be fixed permission .
Tried npm --verbose for debugging but not working
Npm -v does nothing should return the version of npm 3.10.3 ,. Debug is not working windows 11 machine pro operating system. Is there any recommendation need to be done.

have you tried using nvm?

Can you elaborate on npm -v does nothing? Are you getting an error? Does it hang? Does it return immediately?
